# AWS Fargate "memoryReservation" - why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have some trouble to understand the memory management on AWS ECS Fargate.

We can set a **memoryReservation** to our containers, and a "**memory**" limit on our task.

Why should i define reserverd memory on Fargate? I can understand it for EC2 instance types (to select an instance with enough free memory) but on fargate, aws should put the task on an Instance with enough free memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Task Memory** is the total memory available for all container ( its hard upper bound)

**memoryReservation** is a soft lower bound and container can use more memory if required.

This is helpful you have two or more container to in one task definition, to clarify this more we can look into this example

[image]

In this example, we allocate 128 MB for WordPress and 128Mb for MySQL, which become 256MB, which is half of the task level memory but we do not want a situation where container halt because of using max memory so we set hard memory limit to 512 and one container will reached to this the agent will the kill container.

[image]

[deep-dive-into-aws-fargate](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-into-aws-fargate-con333-reinvent-2017)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i dont undertstand what happends when i skip the memoryReservation and set only the memory Limit

Comment: `memoryReservation` this is a soft limit, mean your container can use more memory if required but with `momory` you container will not able use more if required and it killed when it reached to that limit.

Comment: Thanks, but i cant think of the consequence when i skip this setting. Like your example: mysql + wordpress both set to memory 256mb and Tasklimit to 512mb. The only thing i can imagine is that one container gets all memory when started?

Comment: skipping this setting will cause flexibility that we need, for example WordPress receives some abnormal traffic and need some more memory for that and DB seems okay during that particular time, but we set already hard limit so wordpress will not able to handle these request as we harden the memory. so with memory reservation we keep thing flexible until touch the upper limit that is defined in task definition.